# How can i test inside for loop apex test?

Tags: apex, apextestrunresult

[image]

```
 public static List<priceBookEntryWrapper> searchproduct(String sampleId, String seriesValue, list<string> gradeValues){
    system.debug('seriesValue->->->->->->->->->->'+seriesValue);
    system.debug('gradevalues>>>>>'+gradeValues);



    Map<String,priceBookEntryWrapper> backendData = new  Map<String,priceBookEntryWrapper>();

    String setPriceBookId;
    Sample__c p = new Sample__c();
    p=[select Id, Price_Book__c,Full_Fillment_Type__c from Sample__c where Id =: sampleId LIMIT 1];
    if (p.Price_Book__c != null) {
       // System.debug('Id'+pList<priceBookEntryWrapper>.Id);
        System.debug('Price_Book__c'+p.Price_Book__c);
        setPriceBookId=p.Price_Book__c;     
        System.debug('setPriceBookId'+setPriceBookId);

    }

    List<String> conditions = new List<String>();  

    string query='Select PriceBook2.Name,Product2Id,Product2.Stock_Status__c,product2.discipline__c, product2.subject__c,Product2.Name,UnitPrice,Product2.Series__c,Product2.Book_type__c,Product2.Grades__c,Product2.ISBN__c,Product2.Category__c,Product2.Author_Name__c,Product2.Published_Year__c,Product2.IsActive,Product2.Is_Sample__c,Pricebook2Id From PricebookEntry where  (PricebookEntry.IsActive = TRUE OR PricebookEntry.UseStandardPrice=TRUE) AND Product2.IsActive=TRUE AND Product2.Is_Sample__c=TRUE and Product2.Grades__c != null AND Product2.Book_type__c != null AND Pricebook2Id =:setPriceBookId';

    if(seriesValue!=null&&seriesValue!=''){   
        System.debug('seriesValue'+seriesValue);
        conditions.add('Product2.Series__c=:seriesValue');
        system.debug('for series Value>>>>>>>>'+conditions);
    }

    if(gradeValues!=null && gradeValues.size()>0){

                conditions.add('Product2.Grades__c IN : gradeValues');

    }

    if (conditions.size() > 0) {
        for (Integer i = 0; i < conditions.size(); i++)
            query += ' AND ' + conditions[i];
    } 

    list<PricebookEntry> sObjectList = Database.query(query);
    System.debug('sObjectList'+sObjectList);


    Map<String,Boolean> checkvalues1 = new Map<String,Boolean>();
    system.debug('checkvalues1>>>>Map>>>>>>>'+checkvalues1);
    Map<String,Boolean> checkbooktype1 = new Map<String,Boolean>();
    Map<String,Boolean> chkBooktype1 = new Map<String,Boolean>();

  //  Boolean chkBooktype;

    for(PricebookEntry pbe : sObjectList){
        System.debug('pbe'+pbe);    
        Map<String,Boolean> checkvalues = new Map<String,Boolean>();
          Map<String,Boolean> checkbooktype = new Map<String,Boolean>();
        Map<String,Boolean> chkBooktype = new Map<String,Boolean>();
        priceBookEntryWrapper priceEntryObj = new priceBookEntryWrapper();     


        productWrapper prodW = new productWrapper();
        prodW.productId = pbe.Product2.Id;
        prodW.productName = pbe.Product2.Name;          
        prodW.series = pbe.Product2.Series__c;          
        prodW.grade= pbe.Product2.Grades__c;
        prodW.booktype = pbe.Product2.Book_Type__c;
        prodW.UnitPrice= pbe.UnitPrice; 
        if(prodW.series.contains(seriesValue) && prodW.grade != null && prodW.booktype !=null ){
            System.debug('True for map' +prodW.series +' Grade--> '+prodW.grade +'booktype---> '+prodW.booktype);
            if(!checkvalues1.containskey(prodW.grade))
                checkvalues.put(prodW.grade,true);
            checkvalues1.put(prodW.grade,true);
             if(!checkbooktype1.containskey(prodW.booktype)){
            checkbooktype.put(prodW.booktype,true);
            checkbooktype1.put(prodW.booktype,true);
            chkBooktype.put(prodW.booktype,true);
            chkBooktype1.put(prodW.booktype,true);
        }

        }


        priceEntryObj.parentSeries=seriesValue;
        priceEntryObj.reqCourseBookQuantity=1;
        priceEntryObj.reqWorkBookQuantity=1;
        priceEntryObj.reqLiteratureReaderQuantity=1;
        priceEntryObj.reqTeacherBookQuantity=1;
        priceEntryObj.reqTeacherCDQuantity=1;
        priceEntryObj.mapofGrades = checkvalues;
        priceEntryObj.mapofBookTypes=checkbooktype;
        priceEntryObj.mapofcheckBookType = chkBooktype;
        priceEntryObj.prodWrapList = new  List<productWrapper>();
        priceEntryObj.prodWrapList.add(prodW); 
        backendData.put(prodW.productId,priceEntryObj);
    }    
    system.debug('Backend Values'+backendData.values());
    return backendData.values();        
}
```

Comment: Create Test data in test class, such a way that your query will get that data in test execution, will result into `sObjectList ` will not be empty and It will cover your loop

Answer (score 0):

This can be executed after you create records in testclass.As you sObjectList getting 0 records it is not going into the for loop.

Create dummy records in test class so that it will execute the for loop.